# Evolution mail client Privacy

Tags: evolution

Im using ubuntu 11.04 and default mail client as Evolution, Is there any privacy tabs as one found in Thunderbird?

I wanted to block users while opening my evolution mail client, it will show the Mails already downloaded.

In thunderbird I can block by setting a master password which will ask for a master password while entering into the Mail client.

Like wise is there anything in evolution mail client to avoid users from seeing my mails already downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to generally use another account, i. e. "Guest Session" for other users.

Comment: You can look at the mail box files directly without password. So there is no security. Only to use Guest Session and setting the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Your master password is the password that you use for the login. In other words, if during the installation of the OS you choose to encrypt your home directory only your user can decrypt your home and so your mail and so on (look at `~/.config/evolution`) other users will see only an encrypted file.